# React Context and Server Side Rendering: Right way to use React Context for authentication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, server-side-rendering, react-context

I have a requirement where out of multiple routes, I need to (importantly) render one of the static routes on the server to improve the loading speed, this route has content that is independent of the rest of the routes, now the remaining routes are interconnected and I am using React context for authentication, I don't want to do the auth check on the server-side, I just want:

If-> required route -> Show me server-rendered content of that page

Else-> Continue as it used to be (I don't mind if the UI of these page get server-rendered too)

Now my question is, what is the right way to use context in my case. Here's some code:

./src/index.js (Client side code)

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import AuthProvider from "./Context/AuthContext";
import ErrorBoundary from "./ErrorBoundary/ErrorBoundary";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.hydrate(
  <AuthProvider>
    <ErrorBoundary>
      <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </ErrorBoundary>
  </AuthProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

./src/server/server.js

```
import path from "path";
import fs from "fs";

import React from "react";
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";
import express from "express";

import App from "../src/App";
import AuthProvider from "../src/Context/AuthContext";
import ErrorBoundary from "../src/ErrorBoundary/ErrorBoundary";
import { StaticRouter } from "react-router";

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3006;
const app = express();

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  const markup = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <AuthProvider>
      <ErrorBoundary>
        <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={{}}>
          <App />
        </StaticRouter>
      </ErrorBoundary>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
  const indexFile = path.resolve("./build/index.html");

  fs.readFile(indexFile, "utf-8", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error("Something went wrong:", err);
      return res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
    }

    console.log(req.url)

    return res.send(
      data.replace('<div id="root"></div>', `<div id="root">${markup}</div>`)
    );
  });
});

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "build")));

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

AuthContext.js

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import * as AuthService from "../Services/AuthService";
import loadingSvg from "../Assets/loading.gif";

export const AuthContext = createContext();

const Auth = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Even if refreshed, this is the first api call that is going to happen.

    if (localStorage.getItem("user")) {
      setUser(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")));
      setIsAuthenticated(true);
      setIsLoaded(true);
    }
    AuthService.isAuthenticated()
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("isAuth :", data);
        if (data.isAuthenticated) {
          console.log("Updated Auth Check - ", data);
          setUser(data.user);
          setIsAuthenticated(data.isAuthenticated);
          localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(data.user));
          setIsLoaded(true);
        } else {
          console.log("There is some error, please login again. ");
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setIsAuthenticated(false);
          localStorage.removeItem("user");
          setUser(null);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.dir("console err:", err);
        console.log("There is some error, please login again. ");
        setIsLoaded(true);
        setIsAuthenticated(false);
        localStorage.removeItem("user");
        setUser(null);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {!isLoaded ? (
        <div
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
            height: "100vh",
            width: "100vw",
            background: "white",
          }}
        >
        </div>
      ) : (
        <AuthContext.Provider
          value={{ user, setUser, isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated }}
        >
          {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Auth;
```

Also, I am using cookies for authorization and react-router v5.

One more thing,
When I am checking the page source, I am getting the following "root" div

```
<div id="root"><div data-reactroot=""><div style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;height:100vh;width:100vw;background:white"></div></div></div>
```

So the server-side rendering is failing (?)

Answer (score 0):

I think as long as the authentication code is in a `useEffect`, it will only run client-side. So you shouldn't have to change anything, your code should work as-is.

The server-rendering will be done with the initial values you passed to the context provided. Then when the component is hydrated client-side, your useEffect callback will run, and the values will be updated.

useEffect, componentDidMount, and other lifecycle methods don't run server-side. So it's a good way to defer execution of certain logic from the server.